# Plot raster with grid in R

Tags: r, r-grid

I am trying to plot a raster within a plot using grid. The only way I have found so far was via `spplot` from the sp package. Is  there a way to do that directly in grid?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for wanting to use grid? Also, how was the base plot produced? (You can't mix base and grid graphics that easily for example).

Comment: I am doing some plots with grid to have a lot control over the layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at `grid.raster()`?

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. I was walking in circles ;)

Comment: ... all the while you should have been walking on grid. Tsk tsk.